# Setting the href attribute replaces the text of the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

EDIT: I am not talking about the status bar display, I'm talking about the text you click on to follow the link. /EDIT

I looked through a few similar posts and didn't find an answer. I have a link that I want displayed.

www.mylink.com

I want the href of the link to change every time the link is clicked.

href="www.mylink.com?R=340978"

The query string changes to a random number after each click to prevent the browser from caching the page. It's expected that the page will be changing frequently and be viewed frequently to assess those changes.

So I want people to see "www.mylink.com" but the link to lead to "www.mylink.com?R=34532" I thought I would achieve this with an onclick event that would apend a new random number and set the href attribute to the new link, however this is also changing the text that is displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var baseLink = "http://myDevLink/library/ea26098f-89d1-4305-9f75-afc7937f8336/25/test/036b602b-0bde-e011-957b-1cc1dee8bacd.html";
var link = "";

// Prime the link
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    NewRandomParam();
});

function NewRandomParam()
{
    // Make sure one of the warning messages isn't displayed instead of the link        
    if (document.getElementById("link") != null) 
    {
        // Add a random number param to the query string to prevent the user from opening a cached version of the page
        link = baseLink + "?R=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
        document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", link);
    }
}

</script>

<body>

<div id="divContent" style="display:inline; border:0px" class="tab">
<pre style="margin-top: 0;" >
<font face="tahoma">
<a href="" id="link" onclick=NewRandomParam(); target="_blank">http://myDevLink/library/ea26098f-89d1-4305-9f75-afc7937f8336/25/test/036b602b-0bde-e011-957b-1cc1dee8bacd.html</a>
</font>
</pre>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the above code, there is no query string on what should be displayed however when I view the page the value of the href is displayed with the query string. If I do a view source the correct url is there and should be displayed but it isn't.

Please enlighten me on where I'm being dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was a combination of things suggested here plus having to reset the links text to what I wanted it. Here is what worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var baseLink = "<%= this.link %>";
var link = "";

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // Add a timestamp param to the query string to prevent the user from opening a cached version of the page
    $('#link').mouseenter(function () 
    {
        var date = new Date();
        link = baseLink + "?Timestamp=" + date.getTime();
        $("#link").attr("href", link);
        $("#link").text(baseLink);
    });

});

</script>
```

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: After some thought I would think a better way to do it is to use preventdefault on the link and then run a function doing the above on the click handler. My testing showed that changing the href attribute on a normal click just is'nt fast enough, so the link does'nt change before the new page loads, that is why I tried using mouseenter instead, but I think using the click event with preventdefault would be better, but if it works it works, and it's probably not a probelm anyhow, just saying ;-)

Comment: The on click was changing it for the next click not the current. I kind of like this way better but before when the page loaded I would prime the link with the first random number. You would click and go to that one, then it would generate a new link.

Answer (score 0):

Random numbers aren't a good idea here. There's always the chance of getting a duplicated number. Just use `date.getTime()` which should be "random" enough for your purposes.

Changing the href should NOT be changing the text in the link. They're sometimes the same text, but that's by putting the same information in two places (inside the href attribute) and as text inside the `<a>linkname</a>` tag itself. Changing one should never affect the other, unless you've got some other code that keeps things synced.

If you mean you want the change what's displayed in the window status bar when the link's hovered, good luck. most browsers have mechanisms to prevent such fiddling in the first place, as changing the status bar text was heavily abused by spammers and scammers.

Comment: I think I like using the date better. Thank you for the suggestion.

I thought the same thing about changing the href, however thats whats apparently happening. I have no other code that would sync the two. What I showed above is pretty much all the code on the page. The only purpose of this page is to display that url in an iFrame on a CRM page.

The status message is NOT what I'm trying to change. See my comment to the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

      var baseLink = "http://myDevLink/library/ea26098f-89d1-4305-9f75-afc7937f8336/25/test/036b602b-0bde-e011-957b-1cc1dee8bacd.html";
      var link = "";

      $('#link').mouseenter(function() {
         link = baseLink + "?R=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
         $("#link").attr("href", link);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This is an improvement, when the page first loads the link is displayed correctly without the query string param however the first time you mouse over it, the query string appears.

Comment: I don't think I really understood the question, the querystring should not show on the screen when hovering the link, I see you found an answer, but still don't really understand why changing the href attribute changes the link text on you system, as it shouldn't do that, and in my testing there is no need to change the text after changing the hret attribute, must be a strange bug somewhere.

Comment: I don't really understand it either as I didn't think changing the href would change the text either.